# How properly use headers on a Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

please someone can enlighten me on this exemple?

i would like to verify the token with the headers using a GET request and first i've tried to use the authenticate_with_http_token later i've tried to
use

```
@current_user = User.find_by(auth_token:
    request.headers["token"] )
```

istead of

```
@current_user ||= authenticate_token
```

and the same **401 Unauthorized result**.

the case is this is just to verify if the user has the same token as stored in the db.

this is suppose not be complex, but seems to be regarding to tokens.

**code session controller:**

```
 def verify_token

    @current_user ||= authenticate_token

    if @current_user

      render json: {message:"verified",  status: 200}

    else

      render_unauthorized("Token failed verification")
    end
  end


  private

  def authenticate_token

    authenticate_with_http_token do |token, options |
      User.find_by(auth_token: token)
    end
  end
```

**routes**

```
get    'verify'  => 'sessions#verify_token'
```

**postman**

[image]

**logs**

> Started GET "/verify" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-09-06 16:54:45 -0300
>   Processing by SessionsController#verify_token as */*   Parameters:
>   {"session"=>{}} Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (Views: 0.5ms)

Comment: This question is tagged with [jwt], but you're not using it.

Comment: https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/tutorials/token-based-authentication-rails

Comment: is a token in general, i already read this blog is not my case

Comment: It is your case. You're passing the token the wrong way.

Comment: Just so you know, JWT is a very specific kind of token. What you have here is not it.

Comment: no í'm not, i 'm passing the right way. so you gonna help or what?

Comment: "I'm passing the right way" - this article (and a few others) disagree. Let's see if you can spot the difference between your way and theirs.

Comment: you are right so what the difference to use authenticate_or_request_with_http_token under protected?
to authenticate_with_http_token?

Comment: This one should actually be alright, I think. There's another, bigger difference.